# Group the data over partition by sql

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

In my project data, an employee has to use multiple devices for a time period whose last scan time is used to store in the database (like below screenshot)

[image]

I want to write an SQL query to return the start_time and end_time of the device used by an employee, and the total device operating time in secs (like below screenshot)

[image]

I need help from experts here to write an optimized SQL query (compatible with Athena) to achieve the output. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Nobody likes images in these questions. But you'll want to look into min(), max() and as well as date_diff() in athena.

Comment:  Please never post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data.

Comment: Don't worry, these are not real data images. I already tried with max()/min() over(partition by order by ), but did not get success.

Comment: @SandeepKumar we are not worrying that those are real data images

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you GROUP BY staff ID, staff name and device ID, then use min(start_time) and max(end_time)? Please show us your code, even if it isn't fully working.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the table has data for all of history, and you'll want to process by date, so the following query should do what you want:

```
select
x.staff_id,
x.staff_name,
x.device_id,
MIN(last_time) as start_time,
MAX(last_time) as end_time,
date_diff('second', MIN(last_time), MAX(last_time)) as device_operating_time_secs
from x
where date_trunc('day', last_time) = timestamp '2023-06-01 00:00:00'
group by 1, 2, 3
```

You can reference the Trino (engine 3.0)/Presto documentation for SQL syntax help:
https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html